# Salesforce URL Hack not working in lightning, sf1

Tags: urlhacking

Created custom button to pre-populate few fields which overrides standard clone button using url hack, this is working in classic mode but not in lightning mode, sf1.

Please let me if we have any solution.  thanks

Comment: As the term implies, this "hack" isn't officially supported so it isn't surprising that it stopped working.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Lightning Quick action of type create record with predefined values to replace your url hack in Lightning and mobile app. Any url hack is simply not going to work in Lightning and salesforce mobile app.

Read this blog for an working example:- [REPLACING URL HACKS WITH PRE-DEFINED ACTIONS IN LIGHTNING EXPERIENCE](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/05/28/replacing-url-hacks-with-pre-defined-actions-in-lightning-experience/)

Some other Resource available on it:-

1. [Salesforce Mobile App Customization](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app)
2. [Set Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5)
3. [Notes on Predefined Field Values for Quick Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values_notes.htm&type=5)

**Update:-**

Salesforce Does not allow to use Action on Related list but it does the button. You can create a Visualforce page and use that visualforce page inside your button. Redirect user onload the page to the new record page with pre-populated values.

Also, You can explore this open source repository:-
[Quick-Actions-Everywhere](https://github.com/jmdohn/Quick-Actions-Everywhere) which allows to add actions any where in salesforce.

Comment: i need to use this in related list. From related list if click new button i need to prefill some values.